# Root Element is missing-httpwebresponse

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

Iam facing one error as "Root Element is Missing".
My code  is like this.

```
XmlDocument XMLResponse = null;
HttpWebRequest objHttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse objHttpWebResponse = null;
Stream objRequestStream = null;
Stream objResponseStream = null;
XmlTextReader objXMLReader;
objHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
byte[] bytes;
bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb);
objHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
objHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
objHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
objHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "TrnInquiry");
objHttpWebRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
objRequestStream = objHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
objRequestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
objRequestStream.Close();
objHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
if (objHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    objResponseStream = objHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
    objXMLReader = new XmlTextReader(objResponseStream);
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(objXMLReader);
    XMLResponse = xmldoc;
    ds.ReadXml(new XmlNodeReader(xmldoc)); 
    objXMLReader.Close();
}
```

Exception is getting as "Root element is missing"  in the below part

```
xmldoc.Load(objXMLReader);
```

is anything wrong in this.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is being returned by the web request? Most likely your request code is fine, the problem is the response being returned.

Comment: Looks like you may be getting only an element the doesn't include the first line of the xml (identification line).  You could try using xml linq and use XDocument.  It would be helpful if you posted the xml.